# Dereferencing pointers in c

Tags: c, pointers

```
int main()
{
  int a[3][4]={1,2,3,4,4,3,2,1,1,3,4,1};
  printf("\n%d", (a+1));
  printf("\n%d", *(a+1));
  printf("\n%d", (a+1)+2);
  printf("\n%d", *(a+1)+2);
  printf("\n%d",*(*(a+1)+2));
}
```

Why is it that we have addresses despite of deference in all except the last one ?

Also, as per my level of understanding

```
a+1 = 1st position of array
```

`*(a+1) = value at first position` i.e 2 in this case

```
*(a+1) + 2 = 4th position in array
```

`*(*(a+1)+2)) = value at 4th position` which is 4 in this case.

How come output is 2 ?Can I please get some explanation ?
Output:
[image]

Comment: `a` is an array of 3 arrays, each of size 4. So `*(a+1)` (which is just a fancy way of writing `a[1]`) is the second array of size 4, that is a pointer. Using `%d` to print pointers gives you the big numbers you see. `(a+1)+2` is just `(a+3)`, or equivalently `&a[3]`, still a pointer. Your last line is the only one that actually points to an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because only in the last one you completely dereference the pointer. And you should not print addresses with the `"%d"` specifier.

One star, dereferences once, so the result of `*a` has type `int *` which is why it prints an address, when you use two `*` then you dereference the pointer to the value at the right address.

```
   (a+1)    /* &a[1], so no dereference at all                  */
  *(a+1)    /* a[1], so it has type int[3] which decays to int* */
   (a+1)+2  /* &a[3], so no dereference at all                  */
  *(a+1)+2  /* a[3], so it has type int[3] which decays to int* */
*(*(a+1)+2) /* a[1][2], it has type int you finally got a value */
```

Now you expect it to be `4` but look at the way you've initialized your 2d array, it's misleading it should be

```
int a[3][4]={{1,2,3,4},{4,3,2,1},{1,3,4,1}};
```

then

```
a[1][2] -> {4,3,2,1}[2] -> 2
```

so the output is correct.

If you enable compiler warnings it should complain about the wrong format specifier and the braces missing in the initializer list.

Comment: *(a+1) + 2, should not it first deference a+1 , get the value and then add + 2 to the value so as to move to new position  in array ?

Comment: @simikaur remember that in c the first index is `0` not `1`.

Comment: Your answer contradicts with that of Lee Daniel, He has to say it is an array of 3 arrays each of size 4 while you created 4 arrays each of size 3.

Comment: I did at first but then I saw it was `[3][4]` instead of `[4][3]`. Which is why the braces are helpful too.

Comment: `*(a+1)+2` is same as   `(a+1)+2` ? my understanding is that `*(a+1)+2` is equivalent of `&a[2][1]` and `(a+1)+2` is `a[3]`. [code](https://onlinegdb.com/SJcVzAkPO)

Answer (score 1):

`a` is an array of 3 arrays, each of size 4. So `*(a+1)` (which is just a fancy way of writing `a[1]`) is the second array of size 4, that is a pointer. Using `%d` to print pointers gives you the big numbers you see. `(a+1)+2` is just `(a+3)`, or equivalently `&a[3]`, still a pointer. Your last line is the only one that actually references an integer.

Comment: Your answer contradicts with that of iharob He has to say it is an array of 4  arrays each of size 3 while your answer suggests 3 arrays each of size 4 ?

Comment: Easy mistake to make. I believe he's corrected it now.

Answer (score 0):

a is the **array of array** having 3 -1 dimensional array having 4 elements each.

1 dimensional array is of 16 bytes as it has 4 elements and each element is of 4 bytes having declared array as int.

a gives the starting address of 1st element of the array(Here each element is of 1 dimensional array having 4 element in it)  #2358816

(a+1)       = gives starting address for 2nd 1 dimensional array #2358832

*(a+1)      = gives starting address of 1st element of 2nd 1 dimensional array.#2358832

(a+1)+2     = gives starting address of 4 element of the array which does not include in array as there are only 3 -1 dimensional array in an array.#2358864

*(a+1)+2    = give the starting address of the 3rd element of 2nd 1 dimensional array #2358840

`*(*(a+1)+2)`= gives value of 3 element of 2nd 1 dimensional array. #2

Comment: `((a+1)+2)` is equivalent to `a+3` and `((a+1)+2)` is yet another address of an element `&a[3]`. `*(*(a+1)+2)` is the actual value of `a[1][2]`